# What type of HTML5 element/tag would a shop item be?

Tags: html, responsive-design, semantics

Suppose you have to write an html5 only semantic website and now you want to create some items that represent shoppable items.

What type of tag would be most fitting? It's not a `<section>`, nor is it an `<object>`. Div is definitetly wrong since only html5 semantics are desired.

Comment: Could be a section, could be an article, could be a li, could be a button, could be all sorts of things.

Comment: That's sadly the issue with html5 and html5-only exercises, Quintin tarantino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<article>`.

According to the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The `article` element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

This description applies quite well to a card with a product.

Comment: I thought the same but an article to me reads more like an individual thing that's bordered from the next article, you know what I mean? It's hard to explain but articles seem more like their own chapters from the description.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about. You can think of it like this: if it makes sense when separated from the rest of the document (i.e. without context), you should probably use `<article>`, if there's no other more specific alternative.